# Selenium: Parent window closes once child window is open

Tags: selenium, browser, webdriver, parent

I have a scenario and facing problem switching to child window

Scenario:
1. Login Page: Enter user id and password
2. Click on submit button
3. System opens a new full size window (without toolbar or URL bar) and the entire application runs in it
4. As soon as the above child window is opened the parent window (Login Page) is closed

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Posting any [mcve] would be greatly appreciated here. Otherwise, your post may get more down votes and close votes also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
for handle in driver.window_handles:
   driver.switch_to_window(handle)
```

or you can use function

```
driver.switch_to_window("windowName")
```

You can also check http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html for more information about navigating pages with python selenium webdriver.

Note that I have assumed you are using python, if you are using java reference here https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/how-can-i-switch-to-new-window-using-webdriver